# Pinch and Zoom RecyclerView Layout to animate and change the layout manger span count

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

I need to change the GridLayoutManager span count of the RecyclerView with an animation but I need this to be done when the user makes a pinch or zoom gesture on the RecyclerView Layout.Animation should slowly and consistently follow the user's gesture till user releases fingers from screen.

Answer (score -1):

visit https://github.com/mos8502/pinch-and-zoom-layout
you can Pinch and Zoom RecyclerView Layout to animate and change the layout manger span count using this example

mainly the code you want to use is in this class ZoomItemAnimator and methods are decrementSpanCount and incrementSpanCount